# Express router how to route all requests with query parameters?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Router module to route all requests to a specific authorization endpoint.

```
var router = Router();
app.use(router);
router.route('/*')
        .all([auth, function(req, res){
               res.send("Authorized").end();
        }])
```

This works if my request url looks like /myapp/cat. But does not work if it is /myapp/cat?eyecolor=brown.

Is there any specific regex format I need to use to get the router recognize ? character and such?

Comment: Should work. Problem is probably in your `auth` middleware, post its code

Comment: according to documnetation your code should work, i think you are not handling query parameters in your "auth" .

Answer (score -2):

This might help you.

"There is a special routing method, app.all(), which is not derived from any HTTP method. It is used for loading middleware at a path for all request methods."
So I'm not exactly sure about router.route().
http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Second: look at examples of route paths based on regular expressions at the above page. /.*fly$/ accepts butterfly, dragonfly, but not flybird. I think your mistake might be the ' ' of you little regexp.

Comment: Use `.use()` for middleware, not `.all()`. And '/*' is no regex. It will be converted to a regex by path-to-regexp (https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp).

Comment: [`app.use` vs `app.all`](http://google.com/search?q=express+use+vs+all). Basically, `app.all(*)` loops through all HTTP methods while `app.use()` attaches to the application's main middleware stack